# Compare two tables and give the output record which does not exist in 1st table

Tags: sql

I want an SQL code which should perform the task of data scrubbing.

I have two tables both contain some names I want to compare them and list out only those name which are in table 2 but not in table 1.

Example:

```
Table 1 = A ,B,C
Table 2 = C,D,E
```

The result must have D and E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T2.Name
from Table2 as T2
where not exists (select * from Table1 as T1 where T1.Name = T2.Name)
```

See [**this article**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) about performance of different implementations of anti-join (for SQL Server).

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT t2.name
FROM   2 t2
       LEFT JOIN
       1 t1 ON t1.name=t2.name
WHERE  t1.name IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Dale for the reply . I code is working fine. But still i want some explanation I couldn't understand from and left join part.. Can you please give a little explanation?

Comment: LEFT JOIN means take everything from the Left table and only those things from the Right table that match and give me NULLs for the ones that don't. This contrasts with INNER JOIN which gives only those rows that match, RIGHT JOIN which is the logical opposite of LEFT JOIN and CROSS JOIN which gives everything from both tables with NULLs where there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.name
from t2,t1
where t2.name<>t1.name -- ( or t2.name!=t1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DBMS supports it:

```
select name from table2
minus
select name from table1
```

A more portable solution could also be:

```
select name from table2
where name not in (select name from table1)
```